# Tracert ou Traceroute em Java, sem chamar o SO

Tags: java, java-ee, redes

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web que fará o teste do servidores e trará o resultado igual um `tracert` do Windows ou o `traceroute` do Linux. Estou desenvolvendo em Java e usando os comandos citados da seguinte maneira:

Identifico o servidor e chamo:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tracert " + hostCanonicalName);
```

Após a execução eu pego a `String` e monto um gráfico (Vis.js) com o caminho por onde passou a requisição.

Já pesquisei na *web* e não achei nada em Java que faça de forma diferente da mencionada.

Existe algum *framework* que faça isso? Li algo a respeito do `HttpCliente` e não obtive uma resposta satisfatória.

Não quero usar algo diretamente relacionado ao SO e ainda não consegui entender os comandos de forma completa, porque a cada IP que eu testo ele retorna um padrão diferente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu pesquisei também e na primeira página já apareceu resultados interessantes. Não sei se resolvem o que deseja mas parecem ser o que precisa:

- [API independente para *traceroute*](http://jakewharton.github.io/pingdom-java/apidocs/com/jakewharton/pingdom/entities/TraceRoute.html) (aparentemente descontinuado conforme comentário do Victor)
- [Código de uma classe completa](http://people.dsv.su.se/~miko1432/ip/ip1/4.3/doc/_traceroute_8java_source.html) (utiliza a solução seguinte como dependência)
- [Uma solução mais simples - Jpcap](https://github.com/mgodave/Jpcap/blob/master/sample/Traceroute.java) (precisa trabalhar um pouco para obter o resultado)
- [Solução de *ping* encontrada pelo Gordon Christie no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631351/221800)

Código:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Ping {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length != 1) {
                System.out.println("Usage: java Ping <hostname>");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            String host = args[0];
            int timeout = 3000;
            boolean status = InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout);
            System.out.println(host + ": reachable? " + status);
        } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) 
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/Traceroute.java).

O *ping* é a base do *traceroute*. Partindo dele é possível montar um algoritmo para traçar a rota.

Comment: O primeiro link (o do Pingdom) esquece, o autor descontinuou o projeto. Olhando na última tag do github, o código-fonte é apenas um bean com 3 getters. Além disso, aparentemente esta classe não é utilizada mais em nenhum outro lugar do projeto, ou seja, não serve para nada.

Comment: O projeto do segundo link utiliza o que está no terceiro. Acho que é o caminho, caso você não queira usar o código do Gordon Christie por algum motivo.